# SourceSets - Groovy -> Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
sourceSets {
   main {
     java.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin', 'src/main/java']
     res.srcDirs =
       [
          'src/main/res/layouts/activity',
          'src/main/res/layouts/fragment',
          'src/main/res/layouts/dialog',
          'src/main/res/layouts/items',
          'src/main/res/layouts/views',
          'src/main/res/layouts',
          'src/main/res'
       ]
   }
}
```

Here for **java.srcDirs** we convert it in kotlin DSL like

```
java.sourceSets {
    getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
}
```

But I don't know how to change sub folders within 'layout' res folder code in DSL in gradle or don't know it's possible or not? Anyone know if it's possible then how to do that ?

> I want to write `res.srcDirs = []` in DSL as whole Gradle scripts is
>   write in kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Try this

```
sourceSets {
    getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
    getByName("main").res.srcDirs(
        "src/main/res/layouts/activity",
        "src/main/res/layouts/fragment",
        "src/main/res/layouts",
        "src/main/res"
    )
}
```