# Kotlin DSL add new sourceSet

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

On Gradle 6.1.1, how to go around adding sourceSets for android project?

The answer on other questions doesn't work anymore, `getByName("name")` returns error with `SourceSet with name 'main' not found.`

The official document said to use

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("thirdParty/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are over 20 main that has to be imported and I'm not sure which one is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54339367/6021469
This is not working?

Comment: I found the problem, the answer were for pure java projects. For Android, you have to put `sourceSets` inside `android`

Answer (score 9):

I'm using gradle 6.5.1, however documentation suggest, that is should also work for you, try:

```
sourceSets {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("../buildSrc/src/main/java")
    }
}
```

It's also works for build types (debug/release), flavours etc.

Reason for this is that groovy can somehow interpret itself and knows `main` etc., but on gradle kts, you have call it using `named` for already existing, or `getByName`, `create` etc. base on need.

Similiar situation is for `implement` and `api` in groovy you can just use `implementationDebug` to attach it only for debug version, but in kotlin dsl you have to call it as a string `"implementationDebug"`, because there is no such function

----- PS -----

If `named`, `getByName` not works for you, then try to experiment with `findByName` and `create`